# Problems with Photoshop on Wine

Tags: wine, photoshop

I want to run the `photoshopcs5Launcher.sh` in wine
so

I run the command :

```
sudo ./PhotoshopCS5Launcher.sh
```

I get message :

```
wine: /home/srtpl/.wine/wineprefixes/PhotoshopCS5 is not owned by you
```

What is the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `sudo` to run Wine applications. It changes the user ID to root's ID. And running Wine as root is *very, very bad idea*!  Use just

```
./PhotoshopCS5Launcher.sh
```

And it will start.